# Django dynamic carousel uploads

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a django project that can put images I upload into a static file in my application folder.  I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction in making a carousel that automatically takes all images from that folder when the template is refreshed?

I've gotten the code to display the file names in a bootstrap carousel, but I can't get the images.  can anyone help?  The code for my template is as follows:

```
    {% load staticfiles %}
{% load filename %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Minimal Django File Upload Example</title> 
        <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
         <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    {% for document in documents %}
 <div class="item {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        {{document|filename}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    </div>
<!-- /.carousel -->
    <!-- List of uploaded documents -->

        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="{% url 'list' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
            <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
            <p>
                {{ form.docfile.errors }}
                {{ form.docfile }}
            </p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
        </form>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say that you get the file names to show what do you mean? Are you able to get image file names to show or the image url paths to show?

Comment: I technically could do both, but I have a filter that just shows their names for now.  What I want is for just the image to show up on the carousel.

Comment: The part that actually writes the filname to the carousel is the '{{document|filename}}' line

Comment: I am not very familiar with bootstrap but for image to show if you add an image tag to your code ```<div class="col">
        <img src ="{{document|image_url}}" >
      </div>``` would it not work assuming you could get image url instead of filename?

Comment: I thought of that, but it only returns broken images, even though the image url is there...

Comment: how does your image path look? if you return ```/image_path/img.jpg``` it should theoretically work :). Can you print one of the image path in a normal image tag in your html and see if it shows..?

Comment: My most recent one goes to "images/file.png", which I don't think is right.  Should I post more of my code so you can look at it?

Comment: I got it!!! I had to mess around with settings.py